# How to filter out duplicate elements in a group when using PARTITION BY (HIVE)

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

Imagine that I have the following table (animals):

```
**Color**       **Species**    **Weight**
White              Dog            20
White              Dog            8
White              Dog            33
Black              Dog            55
Brown              Dog            80
White              Cat            10
Black              Cat            14
White              Cat            9
```

I want to group by species, filter for unique colors within each species, and find the two lightest animals for each of the filtered groups.

The resulting table should look something like this:

```
**Color**       **Species**   **Weight**  
White              Dog            8         
Black              Dog            55
White              Cat            9
Black              Cat            14
```

I am using the following query (which I know is incorrect):

```
SELECT color, species, weight
FROM (
    SELECT species, color, weight, rank()
           over (PARTITION BY species ORDER BY weight ASC) as rank
    FROM animals) ranked_animals
WHERE ranked_animals.rank <= 2;
```

I don't know how to filter for unique colors in the above code.  Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SAMPLE TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP([COLOR] VARCHAR(20),Species VARCHAR(20), [Weight] INT)

INSERT INTO #TEMP
SELECT 'White' ,             'Dog',            20
UNION ALL
SELECT 'White',              'Dog',            8
UNION ALL
SELECT 'White',              'Dog',            33
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Black' ,             'Dog',            55
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Brown' ,             'Dog',            80
UNION ALL
SELECT 'White',              'Cat',            10
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Black',              'Cat',            14
UNION ALL
SELECT 'White' ,            'Cat' ,          9
```

**QUERY**

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    -- First partition with [COLOR],Species and generate ROW_NUMBER
    SELECT DISTINCT  [COLOR],Species,[Weight],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [COLOR],Species ORDER BY [Weight] ) RNO 
    FROM #TEMP  
)
,CTE2 AS
(
    -- Next  partition with Species only and generate ROW_NUMBER
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Species ORDER BY [Weight] ) RNO2
    FROM CTE
    WHERE RNO = 1 
)
-- Now take new ROW_NUMBER() ie, RNO2 <= 2
SELECT [COLOR],Species,[Weight]
FROM CTE2 
WHERE RNO2< = 2
ORDER BY Species DESC,[COLOR] DESC
```

- [Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a50622/1) to view result

Comment: Although I noticed that for whatever reason, WITH...AS didn't work in Hive for me, so I just rewrote everything using SELECT...FROM ( ) statements.

Comment: You might have missed semicolumn before **WITH**. You can also use **SELECT...FROM ( )** . :) @monkeybiz7